Find min and max of $P = (|a − b| + 3)(|b − c| + 3)(|c − a| + 3)$
For $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$, $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 ⩽ 2$ 
Find min and max value of
$P = (|a − b| + 3)(|b − c| + 3)(|c − a| + 3)$
I don't understand how to find min and max value of an absolute value sign. Can anyone provide some hints for me?

This is not about elementary number theory. Please, read the descriptions of the tags you use.

"I don't understand how to find min and max value of an absolute value sign" Well, by symmetry we can assume wolog $a \ge b \ge c$ and figure $P=((a-b)+3)((b-c)+3)((a-c) + 3)$.  Of course what to do next is another issue.

Let $a\geq b\geq c$, with \begin{aligned} P=&(a-b+3)(b-c+3)(a-c+3)\\=&\frac{1}{100}\cdot 5(a-b+3)\cdot 5(b-c+3)\cdot 4(a-c+3)\\\leq &\frac{1}{100}\bigg(\frac{5(a-b+3)+5(b-c+3)+4(a-c+3)}{3}\bigg)^3\\=&\frac{1}{100}(3a-3c+14)^3\\\leq &\frac{1}{100}(3\times 2+14)^3=80.\end{aligned}
Also, when $a=1,b=0,c=-1$, we have $P=80$.

Since $|x|+3\geq 3$ for all $x$, we have $P\geq 27$
and since $P= 27$ if $a=b=c$ we have $P_{\min}=27$.
